# VS Code merge handler view changed to show incoming/outgoing changes?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github

I use VS Code to handle most my code and to manage branches with GitHub and generally it works like a charm. However today while trying to merge a branch I didn't get a merge handler that allows me to pick and choose which files I want to push. It staged everything and moved it into a all changes section which I've never seen before. The main issue is that I can't unstage files I don't want to change. Is there a way to change back to the old merge handler I'm used to?

TLDR:
My merge handler changed unprompted and I am unsure how to change it back. Below are pictures of the current and old merge handler.

New:

[image]

Old:

[image]

Comment: Please post the code and html as a text, ant an screenshot.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I don't really have any code to post here as this is more of a how to properly use github and vsc question rather then a why isn't my python working question.

Comment: Are you merging histories? Then you have no freedom to choose which files to merge and which you don't want to merge. You cannot take a part of the files now, then come back later, merge the history *again* and take the rest. Git does not work this way. When you merge histories, you get ***one*** chance to say "this is the correct state after the two histories are merged". For this reason, when you ask Git to merge histories, it stages all files as best as it can. Review the result and commit it. You don't get to choose parts.

Comment: @j6t I'm merging a branch into my production one. I've used github and vsc before fine the issue is I have no idea why the layout has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is just due to recent updates adding the incoming and outgoing changes feature. In particular see,

- https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_86#_incomingoutgoing-changes-improvements
- https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_source-control

See the `scm.showIncomingChanges`, `scm.showOutgoingChanges`, and `scm.showChangesSummary` settings.